Passport.js JWT Typescript Conflict with req
middleware:
import { Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { Role } from '@prisma/client';
import { IUserRequest } from '@/interfaces/custom-request.interface';

export const verifyRoles = (...allowedRoles: Role[]) => {
    return (req: IUserRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        if (!req?.user?.roles) {
            return res.sendStatus(401);
        }

        const rolesArray = [...allowedRoles];
        const canAccess = req.user.roles.some(role => rolesArray.includes(role));

        if (!canAccess) {
            return res.sendStatus(401);
        }

        next();
    };
};


Passport:
import passport from 'passport';
import { Strategy, ExtractJwt } from 'passport-jwt';
import { ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET } from '@/constants/environment.constants';
import { prisma } from '@/config/prisma';

const jwtOptions = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey: ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
};

passport.use(
    new Strategy(jwtOptions, async (jwt_payload, done) => {
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: {
                email: jwt_payload.userInfo.email,
            },
        });
        if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
        }
        return done(null, false);
    }),
);

export default passport;

Interface:
import { Request } from 'express';
import { User } from '@prisma/client';

export interface IUserRequest extends Request {
    user?: User;
}

router:
import express from 'express';
import { userController } from '@/controllers/user';
import { Role } from '@prisma/client';
import { verifyRoles } from '@/middlewares/verifyRoles';

export const userRouter = express.Router();


userRouter.get('/', verifyRoles(Role.ADMIN), userController.getAllUsers);
userRouter.delete('/', verifyRoles(Role.ADMIN), userController.deleteUser);
userRouter.get('/:id', verifyRoles(Role.ADMIN), userController.getUser);


This code gives me a Typescript error on the routes, following message:
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following error.     Argument of type '(req: IUserRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Response<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.       Type '(req: IUserRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Response<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.         Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.           Type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to type 'IUserRequest'.             Types of property 'user' are incompatible.               Type 'User | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ id: string; firstName: string; lastName: string; email: string; password: string; roles: Role[]; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; } | undefined'.                 Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type '{ id: string; firstName: string; lastName: string; email: string; password: string; roles: Role[]; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; }': id, firstName, lastName, email, and 4 more

This is because Express Request already has "user" declared...
namespace Express {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
        interface AuthInfo {}
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
        interface User {}

        interface Request {
            authInfo?: AuthInfo | undefined;
            user?: User | undefined;
.......

The callback in passport.ts strategy returns as req.user...
This makes the user a conflict. The custom interface makes it work in the verifyRoles middleware, but in the router file, the middleware gets the TS error described above, because the sent type in that file is addressed as the Express.Request.user, but the middleware expects the custom type I defined.
How do I solve this issue?
I have been trying different solutions, but I'm fairly new to TS so haven't found the solution yet.
